# NullPointerException at RepositoryMongoMetadataProviderImpl.getMetadata java:122

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-roo

I newbie in mongodb and spring roo , I got simple tutorial from the internet, some like :

```
roo> project --topLevelPackage com.yaqin.rooapps
roo> mongo setup --databaseName persondb
roo> entity mongo --class ~.model.Person --testAutomatically
~.model.Person roo> field string --fieldName name --notNull
~.model.Person roo> repository mongo --interface ~.repository.PersonRepository --entity ~.model.Person
```

when create repository mongo, I got error :

```
~.model.Person roo> repository mongo --interface ~.repository.PersonRepository --entity ~.model.Person
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\ave\roomongoap\repository
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\ave\roomongoap\repository\PersonRepository.java
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\ave\roomongoap\repository\PersonRepository.java
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\ave\roomongoap\repository
NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.mongo.RepositoryMongoMetadataProviderImpl.getMetadata(RepositoryMongoMetadataProviderImpl.java:122)
```

anyone can help me, what cause those error ?

- java version : 7
- mongodb version : mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.3-signed
- spring roo version :  spring-roo-1.3.1.RC1

Thanks lot:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a bug. Can you report it on [Spring Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/)?

Thanks!